# C# Self-contained getter for instance

Tags: c#, delegates, getter

I would like to create a self-contained object that is able to access a value of a specific instance. I would like this to be dynamic, so that it can take an arbitrary object and access an arbitrary field or property of that object.

Say I have an instance of the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private int _myValue;
  public int MyValue
  {
    get { return _myValue; }
  }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to create an object that can get `MyValue` with a single call, like so:

```
var myObject = new MyClass();

// somewhere else in code:
myValueGetter.GetValue(); // Returns myObject.MyValue
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you expect `GetValue` to return if there is more than one instance elsewhere in code?

Comment: @JohnWu When I create `myValueGetter`, I'd like to designate the specific instance, as well as whatever property it should access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a lamba.

```
var instance = new MyClass();
var myValueGetter = new Func<int>( () => instance.MyValue);
Console.WriteLine(myValueGetter());
```